# comparing columns in two different tables

Tags: c#, mysql

I am using C#, MySQL to monitor some fuel tanks I'm currently using a function to monitor the tanks that assigns one of three statuses to each tank (good, warning, critical).

One of the things this program has to do is send an email when the tank status changes. What I need help with is how to compare the tank status from 2 different table to determine if the status has changed.

Here are the two tables I'm using:

tank table

```
tank_number INT,
station_id int, 
ip_address varchar(30),
product varchar(30),
alert_level1 int,
alert_level2 int, 
gallons int,
date,
status
```

status table

```
ip_address varchar(30),
status varchar(5),
gallons int,
tank_number int,
date
```

Comment: Are there multiple entries for each tank in the status table or is it one to one?

Comment: no the tank table updates every 15 minutes so only one status per tank

Comment: @PaulBulling, you can add an after update trigger on the status table and have the check logic here. Depending on your knowledge, you can choose further where to implement the email sending mechanism. But for the status change detection, a trigger could help.

Comment: Not a good idea. But use trigger to update another table to store only tank_number and old_status. And while reading it from C# delete the specified row.

Comment: @PaulBulling Status table seems to be subset of tank table and if you are not string audit level data in status then what is the use of status table?

Comment: I made the status table for the comparison to know when the tank status changes I did not make the tank table and cannot make changes to that table and the tank table does not keep history it updates every 15 minutes

Answer (score 0):

This should just be a simple join on the two tables. Something along the lines of:

```
SELECT s.status ,
       t.tank_number
  FROM status s INNER JOIN tank t ON s.tank_number = t.tank_number
 WHERE s.status <> t.status
```

This assumes that tank_number is a unique identifier for the tank and retrieves just those tanks whose status has changed.